# Check if executable exists - run if it is available else exit

Tags: robotframework

I am writing a Robot Script with following logic:

Check that a test executable exists.
If it exists call the executable with arguments.
If it does not exists then log a message and exit as failure,

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation    Test Script to Call an executable from Robot
Library          OperatingSystem
Library          Process
*** Variables ***
${FAILMESSAGE}       Unable to locate the executable
${SUCCESSMESSAGE}    Executing ....
${PATH}          C:\\bin
${BINARY}        tester.exe
${rc}            0

*** Test Cases ***
Test
    [Documentation]    Module Test
    ${rc} = Execute Command dir ${PATH}\\${BINARY}
    Run Keyword If ${rc} == 0 Start Test ELSE Stop Test

Start Test
    Log    ${SUCCESSMESSAGE}
    ${Res}    Run  ${PATH}\\${BINARY}

Stop Test
    Log    ${FAILMESSAGE}
```

However the scripts fails stating **"No keyword with name '${rc} = Execute Command dir ${PATH}\${BINARY}' found."**

Also it goes thru bit Start / Stop Test case and does not logs message to console.

How can I fix the issue as per expectation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have more than one space between your keyword and arguments for robot framework to interpret your commands correctly.

> Two or more consecutive spaces is considered a separator when using the space separated format.

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test
    [Documentation]    Module Test
    ${rc}=    Run And Return Rc    dir ${PATH}\\${BINARY}
    Run Keyword If    ${rc} == 0    Start Test    ELSE    Stop Test
```

I've also changed `Execute Command` because I couldn't find it in the libraries you have imported in your script. [Run And Return Rc](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html#Run%20And%20Return%20Rc) seems to better suit your needs here.

In order to log your output to console there is a [Log To Console](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Log%20To%20Console) keyword you can use and your `Start Test\Stop Test` keywords need to be moved under a `*** Keywords ***` section

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks that solved the issue and I also needed to add keyword section